# Why is Safari cutting off the top of this text?

Tags: html, css, fonts, safari

First, a screenshot.

[image]

… and then with the element selected in the inspector to show boundaries:

[image]

The div surrounding this text wraps it tightly, and the text has a `line-height` of `1em`. The end product renders a div with the ascenders of the text cut off in Safari only. I can find no reason in the compiled CSS for this to happen. Desperately adding all of the usual CSS hack suspects (transform-style, translate3d, backface-visibility) yields no change.

Why the hell might (only) Safari be cutting scalping this text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it turns out that the offending property was… (drumroll)…

↓

↓

↓

↓

↓

↓

`will-change: opacity;`

Changing it to `will-change: unset;` did the trick and my text is back to its pre-scalped beauty.